# What is the correct name for an SVC file in WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, naming-conventions, svc

I'm struggling to come up with the correct naming convention for SVC files (or a group of SVC files). I always call them just that.

`IMyService.cs` goes in `MyProject.Contracts` dll assembly

`MyService.cs` goes in `MyProject.Services` dll assembly

`MyService.svc` goes in `MyProject.????` web application assembly

What's the correct naming convention here. I'm having a complete monday-brain about it and can't get the term facade out of my head which I know is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, an `svc` file represents a *service host* (hence the [@ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx) directive it contains).

So, maybe `MyProject.Hosting` or `MyProject.ServiceHosts` would be appropriate.

Comment: I think ServiceHosts is probably my preference. I'll go with that... Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I would use `.Web`.  It's a web application.

Or possiby, `MyProject.Services.Web` if the `.Web` suffix is already gone?

Comment: I can't... further down my stack I have a .Web Project which is the front end... this is a seperate web project which gets installed on a different server dedicated to backend services.

Maybe .WebServices is good enough.

Comment: @EoinCampbell - yeah `.WebServices` is nice - or how about `.Services.Web`? (Have updated with this suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

We've used `.API` to differentiate it from a regular website front end.